# How to fetch values of column 1 that contain only the given value of column 2?

Tags: sql, join, distinct, where-clause

I want to select names that **only** appear in Mexico and not in any other country.

```
Country      |  Name      
-------------|------------
Mexico       |  Vallejo
Mexico       |  Rachel
United States|  Rachel
UK           |  Rachel
Australia    |  Rachel
Mexico       |  Amy
Canada       |  Amy 
Mexico       |  Annette
Mexico       |  Jennifer
Swahili      |  Jennifer 
Mexico       |  Benedict
```

The correct query would only return  the following names.

```
Name      
---------
Annette
Benedict
Vallejo
```

Any ideas? I'm not sure if this might be a mix of DISTINCT and WHERE conditions.

Comment: No, that will return names that appear in other countries. I need names that ONLY appear in Mexico (Vallejo and Benedict).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
SELECT Name
FROM <table>
WHERE Country = 'Mexico'
AND Name NOT IN (
    SELECT Name
    FROM <table>
    WHERE Country <> 'Mexico')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
      Name 
  FROM table 
  WHERE Name NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
          Name 
        FROM table 
        WHERE Country != 'Mexico'
  )
```

Comment: Whups. Beat me to it. His looks like it might have better performance since it has an extra WHERE clause.

Comment: No worries :) trying it out now

Answer (score 1):

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle using MySQL.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb14f/1)

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    country VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  , name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mytable (country, name) VALUES
 ('Mexico',         'Vallejo'),
 ('Mexico',         'Rachel'),
 ('United States',  'Rachel'),
 ('UK',             'Rachel'),
 ('Australia',      'Rachel'),
 ('Mexico',         'Amy'),
 ('Canada',         'Amy '),
 ('Mexico',         'Annette'),
 ('Mexico',         'Jennifer'),
 ('Swahili',        'Jennifer'),
 ('Swahili',        'Steve'),'),
 ('Swahili',        'Jill'),
 ('Mexico',         'Benedict');

SELECT      name
FROM        mytable
GROUP BY    name
HAVING      AVG((CASE WHEN country = 'Mexico' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.) >= 1
```

*Output*:

```
NAME
--------
Annette
Benedict
Vallejo
```