# What is the HQL equivalent of NOT IN?

Tags: sql, hql, hive

I am trying to use a `NOT IN` keyword in Hive Query Language. It seems to be giving me an error:

```
SELECT Name
FROM names_in_countries
WHERE Country = 'Mexico'
AND Name NOT IN (
    SELECT Name
    FROM names_in_countries
    WHERE Country <> 'Mexico')
```

[Here is the original question with answer in SQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407415/sql-where-and-distinct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Hive Query Language. Based on what I have read here: [**Hive Queries on Tables**](http://karmasphere.com/ksc/hive-queries-on-tables.html#subquery_syntax), following script might work. Give it a try.

*Script*:

```
SELECT      name
FROM        mytable
GROUP BY    name
HAVING      AVG((CASE WHEN country = 'Mexico' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.) >= 1
```

Comment: That was amazing. Thanks for the answer, but this also finally made me understand how you can use AVG, CASE, and other SQL functions more flexibly!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work.

```
SELECT t1.Name 
FROM   names_in_countries t1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Name, 
                               Country 
                        FROM   names_in_countries 
                        WHERE  Country <> 'Mexico') t2 
         ON ( t1.Name = t2.Name ) 
WHERE  t1.Country = 'Mexico' 
       AND t2.Country IS NULL
```

It's crucial to add the `country <> 'Mexico'` on t2 as a sub-select because records retrieved from t2 change after the LEFT OUTER JOIN performed. They appear as NULLs if there isn't a corresponding entry to the record from t1.